# ERROR: ld.so Centos 7

Tags: centos, shared-libraries

help me pls. I have a error when update my gaming server-
 `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/libexec/coreutils/libstdbuf.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing environment variable, you create a symbolic link under the path "/usr/lib"

```
sudo ln -s liblunar-calendar-preload-2.0.so liblunar-calendar-preload.so
```

Then I restart bash.